# Leetcode 207. Course Schedule DFS like solution but not working, looking for error check

Tags: python, graph-theory, depth-first-search

Can one see what is wrong about my python solution. I am a newbie to Leetcoding, thank you for all the help. For those who don't know about the problem: Problem gives you an array of arrays and an integer. Integer stands for number of courses that can be taken by a student, and array is called prerequisites.(https://leetcode.com/problems/course-schedule/)
[[a,b],[b,c]] so for this example of array [a,b] means in order to take course "a" one has to take course "b". It indicates a Directed Acyclic Graph so for the given example:

c----->b----->a

My code returns true for [[1,0],[0,1]] but since there is a cycle it should return false...

```
class Solution:
    def canFinish(self, numCourses: int, prerequisites: List[List[int]]) -> bool:
        import copy as cp
        copyprereq = cp.deepcopy(prerequisites) #copying the given array
        
        for i in prerequisites: # checking for cycles
            searchfor = i[::-1]
            if searchfor in prerequisites:
                return "false"
        
        def dfs(a): 
            takens = []
            if a == []:
                if len(set(takens)) == numCourses: # if lists elements equal to the number given student can take all courses
                    return "true"
                else:
                    return "false"
            for i in a :
                if i[1] in takens and (i[0] is takens) == False: # prerequisite in takens but not course
                    takens.append(i[0])
                    a.remove(i)
                elif (i[i] in takens and i [0] in takens) == False: #none on takens
                    takens.append(i[1])
                    takens.append(i[0])
                    a.remove(i)
                a.remove(i) # both on takens
            dfs(a)
                
        dfs(copyprereq)
```

Comment: You know, the point of 'leetcode' is that you figure stuff out on your own...

Comment: When I call your code with `a = Solution()` / `print(a.canFinish(3, [[0,1],[1,0]]))`, it prints "false".  You do know that `"false"` is not the same as `False`, right?  "true" and "false" are not booleans.  They are strings that both have the boolean value `True`.

Comment: @TimRoberts If you click the question you can see that it returns "true" or "false" instead of True or False. However, probably due to the code file that Leetcode runs my function preseen that both "false" - False or "true" - True returns the same. As far as I see thanks for the comment though.

Comment: You're wrong.  If I click on the question, it's wants a return of `true` or `false`, but that's for C++, where those are the names of the native boolean type.  Your function type hinting has this returning `bool`, and that means you must return `True` and `False`, not the strings `"true"` and `"false"`.

Comment: Thera are a lot typo in your code such as `i[i]`, `i[0] is takens`.And you change the value of loop variable(something after `in` ) while you do loop by using `remove`.I try to fix your code, but found the algorithm itself is also wrong. If you just want to get solution, you can find it in Leetcode.No offence, I think you need learn `DFS` first.

Comment: @leaf_yakitori I know it conceptually but every time I try to implement it i had problems. Maybe I should consume more academic material. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @IDK you can learn `DFS` begin with some simple question, such as solve a simple maze or search a value in a small tree, read the solution code format, such as it always has an exit condition. One time you call the `DFS` function is like one loop, only some special situation you need use an extra loop in `DFS` function.